# Spring Data: string lookup in complex object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have following POJO object:

```
 public class Address {
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String building;
    private String room;
}
```

and following Mongo entity:

```
@Document(collection = "corporateTransport")
public class CorporateTransport {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Address from;
    private Address to;
}
```

Also I have this repository:

```
public interface CorporateTransportRepository extends CrudRepository<CorporateTransport, String> {
}
```

I would like to find all corporateTransport documents where address country like 'Republic'.
How can I do it? Should I write `@Query` or `CrudRepository` can handle it?

Comment: Try querydsl which helps to write queries easily. https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-mongodb. Very easy to plugin and write queries.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries and http://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont actually need the @Query annotation at all.

Try Example:

```
public interface CorporateTransportRepository extends CrudRepository<CorporateTransport, String> {
  List<CorporateTransport> findByFrom_CountryContainingIgnoreCaseOrTo_CountryContainingIgnoreCase(String country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`List<CorporateTransport> findByTo_CountryContaining(String country);`

in `CorporateTransportRepository`.